# unity2d - set camera to fixed size

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera

I am new to unity and I am trying to attach my camera to a fixed background. So I have a camera object, and a sprite object that is the background, but I can't make the camera to be in the exact same height and width of the sprite background.
this is screenshots of my project:

[image: Screenshoot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your camera "size", is actually made up two factors.

1. Orthographic size.
2. Aspect ratio of player.

To fit the background into the camera, change player aspect ratio to be same as background image. And then play with size to let the background cover 100% of camera view size.

I hope it is clear what I am saying, if not let me know.

Comment: thank you it does make sense what you are saying. but how can I modify those attributes? changing the player aspect ratio?

Comment: Go to File -> Build Settings -> Player settings > resolution and Presentation. Here you can set the resolution with correct aspect ratio.

Comment: It all seems to be fine, all aspect ratio are marked, and it looks fine by me... my bg has a width and a height as you can see, and the camera has a different height and width as you can also see in the image I attached. now, when I try to scale the camera, it scales both in y axis and x axis together, so I can't fit the cmera to be exact as the bg.

Comment: I see, so you miss one thing. In Game View change the resolution to the one set in player settings. You can find this in upper left corner of the Game Window.

Comment: awesem! works fine. thank you, you also helped me to understand the way the camera works a bit better.

Comment: I am glad I could help. Cheers